# Android studio documentation popup

Tags: android-studio, popupwindow

Is there a way when documentation popup on AS to not hide immediately after it is showed by moving mouse on some class. What I mean. I move mouse cursor above Activity class and documentation is popup is showed, but when I try to move mouse above this popup (because I have to scroll it) it disappears. I can hold ctrl and then is will not hide, but if I press on it while holdint <kbd>ctrl</kbd> down it will disappear (so I should move cursor above it, release ctrl and after that to start scrolling). So is there an option to change this behaviour to be like in eclipse - documentation pop up is showed and if you move mouse above it you can scroll, otherwise it is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of bugs surrounding this UI element. I'm currently having the opposite problem where it won't go away unless I manually close it. I suspect in your case, a timeout is triggering too early, or some other event is erroneously hiding the window.

This workaround may be helpful. You can explicitly pop the documentation window from the `View > Tool Windows > Documentation` menu option. This will cause the tool window tab to appear on the right gutter by default. Right-clicking on the Documentation tab will pop up a menu that will allow you to pin the window, or dock it permanently in the UI by disabling "Floating Mode" and optionally moving it to the other side or the bottom.

[image: Demonstrative screen shot]